# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ,

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I wrote a simple function that takes in an array and returns a new array that is the inverse of the first. The function doesn't throw any errors, but when I try to insert a variable, I get an unexpected token error alerting me that it doesn't recognize a comma in my execution.

```
var reverseArray = function(arr){
    var last = (arr.length - 1), noo = {};
    for (var i = last; i >= 0; i--){
        noo.push(arr[i]);
    };
    return noo;
};

console.log(reverseArray({1, 2, 3}));
```

Any ideas why this is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(reverseArray({1, 2, 3}));
```

is where the error is: `{1, 2, 3}` is erroneous. An array literal uses `[ ]`, not `{ }`.

```
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3]));
```